# Custom CSS font not loading on homepage first visit

Tags: html, css

I am making a simple website for someone and I want to include some custom fonts in it, namely Open Sans Condensed Light/Bold.

**The font does load.** But **not on the first load** of the page. You have to **click on one of the links** on the page to make the custom fonts load, or have to have visited the website and done that **before**.

This is obviously a problem as first time visitors will be confronted with an ugly looking website. When inspecting the not-working website in firebug, the font-family css part has a greyed out name, meaning it was not activated for some reason.

I use the following code in my CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenBold';
    src: url('opensans-condbold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('opensans-condbold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('opensans-condbold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('opensans-condbold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('opensans-condbold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('opensans-condbold-webfont.svg#open_sans_condensedbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSansLight';
    src: url('opensans-condlight-webfont.eot');
    src: url('opensans-condlight-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('opensans-condlight-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('opensans-condlight-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('opensans-condlight-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('opensans-condlight-webfont.svg#open_sanscondensed_light') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}


body, html{
    font-family:"OpenSansLight";
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
    background-image:url(../images/sintbg1.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;    
}
```

I do include my Stylesheet. My `<head>` looks like

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sinterklaas <? echo $titel?></title>
<base href="http://www.mywebsite.info">
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Anyone have any idea what I can change to make this work? Maybe something I overlooked? I've been struggling with this for almost a week now.

Comment: add your code jsfiddle

Comment: At what folder are the font files located?

Comment: Seems to be a path problem. But you need to be more specify.

Comment: @LaljiTadhani It's an entire website. I can't just upload it to jsfiddle.

Comment: @Orland it's located in the CSS folder.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude if it was a path problem it wouldn't load at all.

Comment: Does it work by loading the external source?

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers? Do you have a link to your website?

Comment: @Orland Yes, and also on other computers and on mobile. The link is www.breunesse.info

Comment: Can you show us any url to reproduce it? Have you seen the network tab on your developer tools? Are the fonts throwing any http error code? Code 200? Code 403? Code 404? Code 500? Please, add more information and sure that we can help you

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I have linked my website in the comments.

Comment: With the url that you provide I haven't any problem. The fonts are loaded fine. Fonts are loaded at the end, maybe there is the problem here. Look at this: http://s7.postimg.org/6lu9fdhnv/prueba.png

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude strange. It doesn't load on the first try on all my computers and on my cellphone. And I have no idea why it would load the fonts last because in the flow, my fonts are at the very top of my CSS file.

Comment: Yes, strange and weird. I am on Windows 7 with firefox 41. I will try in a few moments in a MacOS and I tell you soon.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude any results?

Comment: I am upgrading to Mac OS Captain, so not try yet.

Comment: Works for me in chrome, ff and ie11 on windows 10

Comment: The font works on my end as well.

Comment: Very strange. Really, really weird. Are you sure it worked on the first try?

Comment: Yes. It also works on my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem.
It had to do with my base href.

It used to be the href to my website. Changing it to:

```
<base href="http://<? echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>" />
```

Solved my problem. Turns out the fonts only load when "www" is placed in front of the href or something.
Anyway, I hope this helps someone! I had been looking for the answer for weeks.